# How to load url with read_csv()? It throws error 404

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

Below is my code,i am getting http error not able to understand why...

```
import datetime
import pandas

st = str(1661711400)
et = str(1662143399)
stockcode = 'SBIN'

# interval = "1wk"
# events = 'history'

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+stockcode+'.NS/history?period1='+st+'&period2='+et+'&interval=1wk&filter=history&frequency=1wk&includeAdjustedClose=true'
# s=requests.get(url)

 
stockHistoricalPrice = pandas.read_csv(url)
stockHistoricalPrice.head()
```

Comment: Do you have correct URL? Shouldn't the url be `url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/SBIN.NS?period1=1632600738&period2=1664136738&interval=1wk&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please re-check the url, 404 means the page you are looking is not there.